# Copying CRS from input file for writing to output file in Python without GDAL library

Tags: python, raster, coordinate-system, rasterio

I'm using Python to process rasters that have a CRS. I want to copy the CRS to the raster that is produced.

The rasters are like the following. Sorry, I don't know how to create this from scratch, still learning how to do things in Python (these are mini versions):

```
tmin:
<xarray.DataArray (band: 2, y: 1, x: 1)>
[2 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int32 1 2
  * x            (x) float64 1.426e+06
  * y            (y) float64 -3.82e+05
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:       Area
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM:  20.5
    STATISTICS_MEAN:     -9999
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM:  20.5
    STATISTICS_STDDEV:   -9999
    _FillValue:          nan
    scale_factor:        1.0
    add_offset:          0.0
    long_name:           ('tmin_100', 'tmin_101')
tmin.values
array([[[3.5]],

       [[6. ]]], dtype=float32)
tmax:
<xarray.DataArray (band: 2, y: 1, x: 1)>
[2 values with dtype=float32]
Coordinates:
  * band         (band) int32 1 2
  * x            (x) float64 1.426e+06
  * y            (y) float64 -3.82e+05
    spatial_ref  int32 0
Attributes:
    AREA_OR_POINT:       Area
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM:  3.5
    STATISTICS_MEAN:     -9999
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM:  3.5
    STATISTICS_STDDEV:   -9999
    _FillValue:          nan
    scale_factor:        1.0
    add_offset:          0.0
    long_name:           ('tmax_100', 'tmax_101')
tmax.values
array([[[20.5]],

       [[19. ]]], dtype=float32)
```

A simplified version of the code is

```
import rasterio
import rioxarray as rxr
import numpy as np
import os

# I get an error about proj.db not found without this.
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = 'C:/OSGeo4W64/share/proj/'

# Simplified processing
def calculate_mean(tmin, tmax):
    # Read files
    tmax_src = rxr.open_rasterio(tmax_file)
    tmin_src = rxr.open_rasterio(tmin_file)
    # Change to np.array for calculate_mean
    tmin = tmin_src.values
    tmax = tmax_src.values
    rascrs = tmax_src.rio.crs
    
    result1 = (tmax + tmin) / 2
    return result1


    
tmax_file = "Q:/Shared drives/Data/tmax9.tif"
tmin_file = "Q:/Shared drives/Data/tmin9.tif"


rascrs = rxr.open_rasterio(tmax_file)   
rascrs = rascrs.rio.crs.wkt

tempraster = calculate_mean(tmax_file, tmin_file)

# Define the output file path
output_file = "Q:/Shared drives/Data/results/rhoutput.tif"

# Get the number of layers (365)
num_layers = tempraster.shape[0]

# Get the height and width of the raster
height, width = tempraster.shape[1], tempraster.shape[2]

# Create the output file using rasterio
with rasterio.open(output_file, 'w', driver='GTiff', height=height, width=width, count=num_layers, dtype=tempraster.dtype, crs=rascrs) as dst:
    # Loop through each layer and write it to the file
    for layer in range(num_layers):
        dst.write(tempraster[layer], layer + 1)  # Layers are 1-indexed in rasterio
```

The CRS:

> > > rascrs
> > > 'PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["unknown",DATUM["unnamed",SPHEROID["Spheroid",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",42.5],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-100],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",25],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",60],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]'

When I try to write the raster to file I get this error:

> C:\Users\japolo\Documents\code\pipenvs\pythonrast.venv\lib\site-packages\rasterio_*init*_.py:329:
> NotGeoreferencedWarning: Dataset has no geotransform, gcps, or rpcs.
> The identity matrix will  be returned.   dataset = writer(

I've seen other questions and resources that say to use GDAL library for Python. But I can't install GDAL in my Python environment because of some kind of problem due to Microsoft C++ versions. ( I have 2015-2019 and the error says "2014 or greater". Go figure. )  It seems like the `crs=rascrs` should work, but since it's not, my new raster files lack the geographic information. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CRS alone is not enough to georeference a raster, you also need to specify the `transform` when opening the output file, by copying that from the input:  https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.html#rasterio.open

Comment: The code would be something like `ras_trans = rascrs.rio.transform()` and the write statement like: `with rasterio.open(output_file...,  crs=crsras, transform=ras_trans)`.